# Help-limits with integral part

Tags: analysis

Can you help me to find the limits?
$$\lim_{x \to 0^{+}}\frac{x}{a}\left[\frac{b}{x}\right]  , \quad \lim_{x \to 0^{+}}\frac{b}{x}\left[\frac{x}{a}\right], \quad a,b>0$$ 
And what happens when $x \to 0^{-} $  ?

Comment: What does $[\frac{b}{x}]$ mean, is that a special notation for something?

Comment: I guess it's the biggest integer

Comment: It is the integral part!!!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For the first: we have
$$\Bigl[\frac{b}{x}\Bigr]=\frac{b}{x}-\varepsilon(x)\ ,$$
where $0\le\varepsilon(x)<1$.  Hence
$$\frac{x}{a}\Bigl[\frac{b}{x}\Bigr]=\frac{b}{a}-\frac{x}{a}\varepsilon(x)
  \to\frac{b}{a}$$
as $x\to0^+$, beacuse the second term lies between $0$ and $x/a$.

For the second, as soon as $x<a$ we have $[x/a]=0$ and so
$$\frac{b}{x}\Bigl[\frac{x}{a}\Bigr]=0\to0$$
as $x\to0^+$.

Comment: Since we know that $[x]\leq x \geq [x]+1$,could we use this relation instead of the one that you used?? 
I applied it and got: $$\frac{b}{a}-\frac{x}{a} \leq \frac{x}{a}[\frac{b}{x}] \geq \frac{b}{a} $$..Can we say that the first limit is $0^{+}$ ..And,what's about $x\to O^{-}$.Is this the same result??

Comment: The second $\ge$ in your comment should be $<$.  If you fix this it should be OK.  I haven't looked at the $x\to0^-$ case.  The same ideas should work, though the answers could possibly be different because for negative $x$ the integer part rounds away from $0$.  For example $[\frac{3}{2}]$ is $1$ but $[-\frac{3}{2}]$ is $-2$, not $-1$.  See what you can do.

Comment: Using the same relation for the second limit,I have found the following:
$$\frac{b}{a}-\frac{b}{x}\leq \frac{b}{x}[\frac{x}{a}] \leq \frac{b}{a}$$

What does this mean??That the limit does not exist???Or have I done something wrong??

Comment: If you are trying to use the Sandwich Theorem (Pinching Theorem) it will not apply here and you will have to use other methods.

Comment: I got stuck right now...Could you give me a hint??

Comment: I would just do it as in my original answer.  No point making it complicated.

Answer (score 1):

This Limit does not exists!

Just look at the subseries $x_n=n$ and $x'_n := 0.9+n$

Comment: Which limit do you mean that does not exist???the second one??

Comment: hmm I guess both! let me see

Comment: Could you check what I have done? Since we know that $[x]\leq x \leq [x]+1$,could we use this relation instead of the one that you used?? 
I applied it and got: $$\frac{b}{a}-\frac{x}{a} \leq \frac{x}{a}[\frac{b}{x}] \geq \frac{b}{a} $$..Can we say that the first limit is $0^{+}$ ..And,what's about $x\to O^{-}$.Is this the same result??

Comment: ah sorry im totally wrong! I did not see $x\to 0$, they both exists.

Dont make it so complex! wait i edit my post